# wrapper not covering the nested divs

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyfrancisjoseph/2EfLz/1/

The following is a code that I wrote. The problem is that in the resulting page the wrapper div does not seems to container the nested divs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your body elements, `#left-container`, `#right-container`, are being floated they are being removed from the regular content flow, so you will need a "clearfix" to properly contain the floated elements. You can do that in two ways:

One, by Using a clearfix, like the following, my preferred approach since its inline and doesn't mess with the absolutely positioned elements that might be overflowed out of the container:

```
#wrapper:before, #wrapper:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}

#wrapper:after {
    clear:both;
}

#wrapper {
    *zoom:1; /* ie7 hasLayout fix */
}
```

Or two by using `overflow:hidden` on your `#wrapper` container, a method which i try to avoid since you might have positioned elements that might overflow out of your container with `positition:absolute`, so they will be cutoff with that method. A third option would be to add a  at the end of your container, but that is just an icky approach :).

Demo with the first (and my preferred) approach http://jsfiddle.net/2EfLz/2/

Comment: Add `wrapper{*zoom:1;}` for ie7 support.

Comment: @JamesSouth IE - the life of the party, i always forget about it but you're right.

Comment: Ilich: Hehe.. We'll al be glad when it fades away.

Answer (score 3):

add "overflow: hidden;" to your wrapper's definition.

Answer (score 1):

you give **overflow:hidden** in your **#wrapper**

```
#wrapper
{
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#999;
    width:960px;
    border:dashed #006 thick;
    overflow:hidden;


}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2EfLz/3/

Answer (score 1):

use `overflow:hidden;` in wrapper style.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this **position: absolute;**

```
            #wrapper
           {
            margin:0 auto;
            position: absolute;
            background-color:#999;
            width:960px;
            border:dashed #006 thick;

         }
```